# Numbers at the corners of concentric squares (part 2)

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

[image]

Put 4 distinct 1-digit non-negative numbers (A, B, C, D) on every vertex of a rectangle.

Then put the last digit of the product of 2 connected vertices at the sides of the rectangle.

Create a smaller rectangle connecting the sides of the bigger rectangle.

Do the above procedure **5 more times** (using the 4 new numbers which do not have to be distinct).

**The last 4 numbers must be (1,1,1,1).**

```
E = last digit of (A×B)           G = last digit of (B×D)
H = last digit of (C×D)           F = last digit of (A×C)
I = last digit of (F×E)           J = last digit of (E×G)
K = last digit of (F×H)           L = last digit of (H×G)
and so on....
```

Find (A, B, C, D)

Note: Every permutation of (A,B,C,D) will yield the same result (1,1,1,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that

> 9, 7, 3, 1

is working. I found this by computer.

Answer (score 6):

The stage before $(1,1,1,1)$ must be

> one of $(1,1,1,1)$ itself,
>  $(9,9,9,9)$, or
>  $(3,7,3,7)$ - 7 opposite 7 [& 3 opposite 3] ($3\times 3$ and $7\times 7$ do not end in $1$.)
>  - thanks to Etoplay for spotting the last one, I totally discounted it when considering the multiplication noted above!

the stage before

> a $(9,9,9,9)$ must be
>  one of $(3,3,3,3)$, $(7,7,7,7)$, $(1,9,1,9)$ - with 9 opposite 9 [and 1 opposite 1]

now

> the $(3,3,3,3)$ needs $(1,3)$ or $(7,9)$ pairs, not getting us further toward the outer distinct requirement

similarly

> the $(7,7,7,7)$ needs $(1,7)$ or $(3,9)$ pairs.

but

> For the $(1,9,1,9)$ we can shift the opposite pairs by using $(3,7)$ and $(7,3)$

and then

> break the $(3,3,7,7)$ into $(3,1,3,9)$ which we can then break into $(1,3,7,9)$.
>
>  This does it in five steps, but $(1,1,1,1)$ goes to $(1,1,1,1)$.

which yields a solution of

> $(1,3,7,9) \rightarrow (3,1,3,9) \rightarrow (3,3,7,7) \rightarrow (9,1,9,1) \rightarrow (9,9,9,9) \rightarrow (1,1,1,1) \rightarrow (1,1,1,1)$

---

We can also see that

> the $(3,3,3,3)$ and $(7,7,7,7)$ both take us out to useless trails containing the patterns $(1,3,1,3)$, $(7,9,7,9)$, $(3,3,3,3)$, $(7,7,7,7)$, $(1,7,1,7)$, $(1,9,1,9)$, and $(3,9,3,9)$.

If we try with the

> $(3,7,3,7)$ found at the start we see that we can go directly to $(1,3,9,7)$!

Checking the

> $3024$ possible starting arrangements (ignoring $0$ since it will only lead to more zeros) the valid ones are indeed all $24$ permutations of $(1,3,7,9)$:
>
> ```
> from itertools import combinations, permutations
> target = [1,1,1,1]
> for choice in combinations(range(1, 10), 4):
>     for outerSquare in permutations(choice):
>             squares = [list(outerSquare)]
>             while len(squares) <= 6:
>                     nextIn = [(x*y)%10 for x,y in zip(squares[-1], squares[-1][1:] + [squares[-1][0]])]
>                     squares.append(nextIn)
>                     if nextIn == target:
>                             break
>             else:
>                     continue
>             print(squares)
>
> [[1, 3, 7, 9], [3, 1, 3, 9], [3, 3, 7, 7], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[1, 3, 9, 7], [3, 7, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[1, 7, 3, 9], [7, 1, 7, 9], [7, 7, 3, 3], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[1, 7, 9, 3], [7, 3, 7, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[1, 9, 3, 7], [9, 7, 1, 7], [3, 7, 7, 3], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[1, 9, 7, 3], [9, 3, 1, 3], [7, 3, 3, 7], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 1, 7, 9], [3, 7, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 1, 9, 7], [3, 9, 3, 1], [7, 7, 3, 3], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 7, 1, 9], [1, 7, 9, 7], [7, 3, 3, 7], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 7, 9, 1], [1, 3, 9, 3], [3, 7, 7, 3], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 9, 1, 7], [7, 9, 7, 1], [3, 3, 7, 7], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[3, 9, 7, 1], [7, 3, 7, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 1, 3, 9], [7, 3, 7, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 1, 9, 3], [7, 9, 7, 1], [3, 3, 7, 7], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 3, 1, 9], [1, 3, 9, 3], [3, 7, 7, 3], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 3, 9, 1], [1, 7, 9, 7], [7, 3, 3, 7], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 9, 1, 3], [3, 9, 3, 1], [7, 7, 3, 3], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[7, 9, 3, 1], [3, 7, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 1, 3, 7], [9, 3, 1, 3], [7, 3, 3, 7], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 1, 7, 3], [9, 7, 1, 7], [3, 7, 7, 3], [1, 9, 1, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 3, 1, 7], [7, 3, 7, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 3, 7, 1], [7, 1, 7, 9], [7, 7, 3, 3], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 7, 1, 3], [3, 7, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> [[9, 7, 3, 1], [3, 1, 3, 9], [3, 3, 7, 7], [9, 1, 9, 1], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
> ```

Comment: Can't the second square be (3,7,3,7) only 3 and 7 will be multiplied. No 3*3 or 7*7.

Comment: Err, yes it could.

Comment: I didn't follow your reasoning closely, but in the last line you argue that you verify your solution. However, OP states that *all permutation* of the initial quadruple should lead to the (1,1,1,1) final state which in effect multiplies up your *quick check of ... possibilities* by a factor 24.

Comment: @Matsmath as noted by Etoplay I missed a choice at the start, which indeed leads to a shorter path to the same choices.

Comment: @Matsmath - thanks by the way! I updated to include permutations - it is still very quick I must say.

Comment: I made a [graph of the solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i93Rx.png) for those interested.

Answer (score 3):

> 1, 3, 7, 9.

I almost went to code this but figured it out in my head. Great puzzle!

> Any odd number number times an even number gives an even number, and numbers have to be odd. If only one of A, B, C, or D is even, all numbers will be even by the third iteration of the procedure. So A, B, C, and D are all odd. This narrows it down to 5 options.

.

> Did someone say 5? Well, any odd number times 5 ends in 5, so if 5 is one of A, B, C, or D, then all numbers will be 5 by the third iteration of the procedure. This excludes 5.

.

> All that remains are 1, 3, 7, and 9. The first iteration of these numbers yields 3, 7, 3, and 7, which then yield 1, 1, 1, 1.

.

> You only need to do the procedure twice to get this result. Why stipulate 6 iterations? To make it more daunting?

.

Comment: 6 iterations guarantees that any combination of those numbers works. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Labelling the corners of the first square consecutively as $A,B,C,D$; the corners of the subsequent squares are:

- $AB, BC, CD, AD \pmod{10}$
- $AB^2C, BC^2D, ACD^2, A^2BD \pmod{10}$
- $AB^3C^3D, ABC^3D^3, A^3BCD^3, A^3B^3CD \pmod{10}$

So we can already rule out any of $A,B,C,D$ being in

> $\{0,2,4,5,6,8\}$ since we end up with $1$s and so $ABCD$, which divides all of the corners from here on in, must be coprime with $10$.

But then by elimination we have

> $\{A,B,C,D\} = \{1,3,7,9\}$.

To verify that these work in any order, we can continue for the remaining three squares:

- $A^2B^4C^6D^4, A^4B^2C^4D^6, A^6B^4C^2D^4, A^4B^6C^4D^2 \pmod{10}$
- $A^6B^6C^{10}D^{10}, A^{10}B^6C^6D^{10}, A^{10}B^{10}C^6D^6, A^6B^{10}C^{10}D^6 \pmod{10}$
- $A^{16}B^{12}C^{16}D^{20}, A^{20}B^{16}C^{12}D^{16}, A^{16}B^{20}C^{16}D^{12}, A^{12}B^{16}C^{20}D^{16} \pmod{10}$

And then observe that the innermost square is $$(A^4B^3C^4D^5)^4, (A^5B^4C^3D^4)^4, (A^4B^5C^4D^3)^4, (A^3B^4C^5D^4)^4 \pmod{10}$$ and that

> $1^4 \equiv 3^4 \equiv 7^4 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$

Comment: Proof from the book.